# Circle locus, how to satisfy the equation.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

> $A(-3,1), B(0,-5), P(X,Y)$
>
> If $|AP| = 2|BP|$ prove that $x$ and $y$ satisfy the equation:
>
> \begin{aligned}
>   \ x^2+y^2-2x+14y+30 =0
>   \end{aligned}

I get as far as determining the co-ordinates like so

\begin{aligned}
\ \sqrt{(x+3)^2+(y-1)^2}= 2\sqrt{(x)^2+(y+5)^2}
\end{aligned}

To

\begin{aligned}
\ x^2+y^2+2y+40-6x =0
\end{aligned}

Which gives me $(3, -1)$, this won't satisfy, is my method correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we start from the equation
$$
\sqrt{(x+3)^2+(y-1)^2}= 2\sqrt{(x)^2+(y+5)^2},
$$
and square both sides, we obtain the equivalent equation
$$x^2+6x+9+y^2-2y+1=4x^2+4y^2+40y+100,$$
which simplifies to 
$$3x^2+3y^2-6x+42y+90=0,$$
which is equivalent to
$$x^2+y^2-2x+14y+30=0.$$

**Comment:** Draw the line segment that joins $A$ to $B$. It is fairly easy to see that $(-1,-3)$ is the point on this line segment that is twice as far from $A$ as it is from $B$.  So $(-1,-3)$ ought to be on our circle, and indeed it is.  That provides a partial check on the correctness of our computations.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 2x^2+2y^2+20y+50?

Comment: No, when you square both sides you need to square the "$2$". If $a=2b$ then $a^2=(2b)^2=4b^2$.